# Why is the Butterfly Miraculous seemingly the most powerful?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

In Miraculous Ladybug, the Ladybug and Cat Miraculouses are supposed to be the strongest. We know this from the fact that, when combined, they give ultimate power, and from their fact that their kwami are the oldest and most fundamental (creation and destruction). This may even have been explicitly stated. By contrast, the Butterfly Miraculous seems to be in the same "tier" in the box as more modest powers such as the Turtle, Bee, and Fox.

However, the Butterfly Miraculous seems notably more powerful. Hawk Moth probably can't choose the powers of his minions, and he has little guarantee that they'll listen to him, but a typical akumatized villain has abilities much stronger than Cataclysm or Lucky Charm, often covering s broad area, which further usually can be used more than once, giving Ladybug and Cat Noir a hard time two-on-one, and the akumatization also seems to have little time limit (let's not even talk about what happens if the akuma isn't purified!).

Why is the Butterfly Miraculous seemingly so strong?

Comment: Admittedly, the akumatized villain is usually (? I’m not up to date!) defeated by the end of the episode, plus Ladybug's powers restore pretty much **everything** back to how it was. It’s also not clear how long the powers last unchecked. It might be a case of a faster, more powerful burn.

Comment: Likewise, Cataclysm can destroy **anything**, while the akumatized powers (while often including reality-warping) are a lot more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chalk this up to **a strong Miraculous in the hands of a skilled wielder.**

There are really two embedded questions here, so I'll tackle them separately.

---

**1) Why is the Butterfly so powerful?**

In "Catalyst (Heroes' Day Part I)", Master Fu says the following:

> "I always knew that one day Hawk Moth would realize just how powerful he could be.  That day has come, Marinette."

In the two-part season 2 finale, Hawk Moth grants his assistant the ability to boost others' powers, who in turn boosts Hawk Moth's own abilities and allows him to simultaneously akumatize as many people as he likes.  Clearly, Master Fu was aware that this, or something like this, was possible and admits that Hawk Moth has the potential to be a terrifying threat.

---

**2) Why is the Butterfly *more powerful than all the others*?**

This is simply the result of Gabriel Agreste being a skilled user; the Butterfly is not inherently the most powerful Miraculous.

In "Timetagger," we see an adult Miraculous user (who isn't Hawk Moth) for the first time, and she is able to use her power over and over again without needing to transform back-- which confirms what Hawk Moth says in @Cat_Noir's answer.  So this ability is not unique to Hawk Moth or Gabriel Agreste personally, but is a measure of his skill.  Obviously, someone who can use their power at will would be stronger than someone who can't.

So how does the Butterfly's akuma ability measure up?  It's strong, for sure, but is it the strongest?  Consider this exchange between Master Fu and Plagg, from "Style Queen (The Queen's Battle Part I)":

> Master Fu: "Does the disappearance of Atlantis ring a bell with you?"
>
> Plagg: "I'd had too much cheese..."
>
> Fu: "The leaning tower of Pisa?"
>
> Plagg: "I didn't see it."
>
> Fu: "*Dinosaurs?*"
>
> Plagg: "Oh yea, I did go too far there.  But I was young!"

Imagine a villain with *that* kind of destructive power! Hawk Moth might be capable of some impressive feats, but nothing quite so world-altering as Plagg's.

Answer (score 10):

## Hawk Moth is the most skilled Miraculous holder

Hawk Moth makes the Butterfly Miraculous seem more powerful than it actually is because he is the most skilled Miraculous holder we've seen so far.

#### Example

Once Ladybug or Cat Noir use their power, they have five minutes until they transform back into civilian form. Hawk Moth does not have this limitation.

In a scene where Hawk Moth fights Ladybug and Cat Noir directly, he mocks them for their inexperience:

> **Hawk Moth**: You're still so green, young superheroes. You can't even stay transformed after you've used your powers.
>
> <sub>- Miraculous Ladybug Season 2 Episode 25 "Mayura (Heroes' Day - Part 2)"</sub>

He says that they have the five minute limitation because they are inexperienced. This implies that his superior experience (not his particular Miraculous) allows him to stay transformed.

Comment: Wang Fu is likely to be more skilled, we just don't see him do much.

Answer (score 2):

But Lucky Charm is not the most powerful application of Lady Bug's creation power we've seen.  Instantly rebuilding all of Paris no matter what damage has been done to it is.  Which means that Chat Noir could probably destroy entire cities if he didn't restrain himself.  Ladybug and Chat Noir haven't tapped the full power of their talismans.  And it's probably better for the world if they never do.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel Agreste is basically the most experienced, although it's because he had nooroo for a long time as i heard, then somewhat had the peacock. he even mocked them saying that they needed a limit

Pretty sure if they didn't HAVE the limit, pretty sure he would've already been destroyed.

Plagg is basically dangerous and could literally destroy cities even the whole world, we see that in the Chat blanc episode.

Cat Noir and Ladybug are still teenagers, and basically have a time limit, but once they get older i'm for sure Hawk Month would've been so destroyed easily

Which in my prediction, is why timetagger went to the past so he could take away their jewels. as in  Miraculouses. They seem more stronger since they're adults and could use their powers over and over again.

The only reason why the butterfly seems so powerful because he has more experience and could use the power over and over again without needing to recharge like marinette and adrien have to and he could get everyone akumatized, but that isn't really happening since they only take advantage when they have negative emotions happening

Plus you don't even need to fight, you can just have people fight for you

**Then again, Ladybug and Chat will be stronger in the future when they're adults after all.**

but for now

The butterfly will stay as the most "powerful" just because of everything of being so.. well any ability could seem powerful then tikki and plagg.

but once they're adults i'm sure they're unstoppable in the future ^^

although, hawk moth could possibly make abilities stronger than the abilities chat and ladybug have

oh well, we'll see eventually :)

Comment: You make the same point multiple times so this could do with being [edit]ed down and condensed so it’s not just reiterating the same thing again and again. It would also be helpful to add in some evidence to back up this point that, that is why it’s stronger.

Answer (score -1):

This was basically talking about how the butterfly seems powerful right now, the lucky charm, the repairs everything seems powerful, the ability to destroy things is basically really dangerous

which is why dinosaurs are extinct

They could find more about their powers that nobody knows yet, we don't know exactly

although, it could be dangerous they might just not be able to control themselves

including chat noir.

His power is too dangerous and could end the earth at this point

Hawk Moth could also do the same and find out more about his power like he became scarlet moth, a hard day for Ladybug and Chat Noir

I explained how basically Chat and Ladybug are still stronger, but they have time limits, unlike hawk month as i said before

Hawk moth is basically well skilled lol

the butterfly isn't really the most powerful

but once chat noir and ladybug are really experienced i'm sure they'll be more powerful than him lol

Comment: This is an extension of your previous answer. Instead of adding a new answer you should really edit the old one as explained on it.